# Django ckeditor can not add youtube plugin

Tags: python, django, plugins, youtube, ckeditor

I have seen this tutorial https://samulinatri.com/blog/django-ckeditor-codesnippet-hightlightjs-youtube/ and I have downloaded the youtube plugin here https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube

Then I created the youtube folder and pushed it into it. Specifically my_project / static / ckeditor / ckeditor / plugins / youtube /

After I python manage.py runserver, field ['content'] show normal, field ['content1'] it doesn't work (does not display frames textarea).

Someone helped me check, I did something wrong. Thanks !!!

## File model.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(extra_plugins=['codesnippet'],)
    content1 = RichTextUploadingField(
        config_name='special',
        extra_plugins=['youtube'],
        external_plugin_resources=[(
            'youtube',
            '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/youtube/',
            'plugin.js',
        )],
    )
```

## File setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
     },

    'special': {
        'toolbar': 'Special',
        'toolbar_Special': [
            ['Bold'], ['CodeSnippet', 'Youtube'],
        ],
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codesnippet', 'youtube']),
    }
}
```

## File urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include(('accounts.urls', 'accounts'), namespace='accounts')),
    path('blog/', include(('blog.urls', 'blog'), namespace='blog')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    debug_patterns = [
        re_path(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
    urlpatterns = debug_patterns + urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## My_project

```
├── blog                          <= This my_app
│   ├── view.py             
│   ├── form.py
│   ├── model.py
├── project                          <= Project settings directory
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py          <= settings 
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py 
├── static                         
│   ├── ckeditor           
│       ├── ckeditor_uploader
│       ├── ckeditor        
│           ├── plugins
│               └── youtube   
│                   └── youtube  
│                        └── images
│                        └── lang 
│                        └── plugin.js
│                        └── ....
│                   └── ...  
│                └── ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py` file, you need to point to the directory where the `plugin.js` is.

I believe the directory you should refer to is this:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(extra_plugins=['codesnippet'],)
    content1 = RichTextUploadingField(
        config_name='special',
        extra_plugins=['youtube'],
        external_plugin_resources=[(
            'youtube',
            '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
            'plugin.js',
        )],
    )
```